# In vb.net application AxWindowsMediaPlayer does not work on client machines

Tags: vb.net, dll, com, windows-media-player

I have added COM control AxWindowsMediaPlayer to form in vb.net.

and just have following code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WMPlayerVideo.URL = "abase.mp4"
    End Sub

End Class
```

abase.mp4 file is kept in directory where exe is there. Every thing runs fine on dev m/c but on client machine application is not lauached.

When Interop.WMPLib.dll and Interop.WMPLib.dll are copied to the exe file directory then application is lauched at least but file is not played automatically and even on pressing play button its not played.

Is some dll registration required to make it work? or some references needed in project?
or some changes on user machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the DLLs is required, it cannot work otherwise.  Which leaves the location of the file.    You are only giving the relative location of the file, not the full path (like "c:\mumble\foo.mp4").  On your machine, this file needs to be stored in the bin\Debug folder of your project directory to make it work.  Another machine you deploy your program to isn't going to have a bin\Debug (or Release) folder.  It still needs to be present in the same directory as the EXE.  Maybe you forgot to copy the .mp4 file?

Clearly you'll want to provide the user with a way to select the file.  Use OpenFileDialog.

Comment: Yaah i used the file dialog box to select the file and i also used reg free com method. In properties of WMPLib file in references folder (seen in 'show all file' option in solution explorer) , i set the isolated property to True. Its default value is false. So setting it to true generated the dll file, manifest file after running the project. When all these files are copied on client machine, windows media player finally started. http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc188708%28en-us%29.aspx